# Passing a component's dimensions down to another nested component in Ember

Tags: ember.js

In the layout I'm working on (based on this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/TBnqw/2288/)), a nested component (the sticky scrollbar) depends on the parent component's dimensions, so I'm passing these dimensions down as attributes. Something like:

```
{{!-- Rest of the template --}}

{{div-scroller 
  width=tracksWidth offset=tracksOffset
  scrollWidth=tracksScrollWidth scrollLeft=tracksScrollLeft 
  scrollUpdated=(action "updateComponentScroll") }}
```

The problem is that in Ember's component lifecycle, you can only get the dimensions for a component after `didInsertElement`. If I try to do this:

```
didInsertElement( ...args ) {
  this._super( args );

  // Get dimensions
  this.set( "tracksWidth", this.$().width() );
  this.set( "tracksOffset", this.$().offset() );
  this.set( "tracksScrollWidth", this.$().get( 0 ).scrollWidth );
  this.set( "tracksScrollLeft", this.$().scrollLeft() );
  this.set( "lastScrollPosition", this.$().scrollLeft() );
}
```

Ember complains that I should not set properties in the `didInsertElement` (or in `didRender`) for performance reasons.

Is there any other way of passing a parent component's dimensions to a child component?

Comment: Maybe its not possible with your use case but did you try addon to do this for you? I made perfect scrollbar wrapper [ember-cli-scrollbar](https://github.com/Keeo/ember-cli-scrollbar), to help me with this.

Comment: Thanks, Keo. I actually tried your wrapper, as well as perfect-scrollbar on its own, but it didn't work. My layout is a bit complex and the div I need the scrollbar for has two scroll parents: the vertical scrolls that div with its sibling and it's attached to the parent, while the horizontal scrolls only that div (and not the sibling) and it's on the div itself.

Comment: I see, well one think that I would try (but will have probably some issues) is  to wrap setters into `Ember.run.later` or  `Ember.run.scheduleOnce('afterRender',...)` [scheduleOnce](http://emberjs.com/api/classes/Ember.run.html#method_scheduleOnce).

Comment: Your solution works, but now I found a different issue: when coming from another route (and not from a refresh, for example) it gets the div dimensions wrong. That's a different question, though, so if you want, post that comment as an answer and I'm happy to mark it as a solution. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it by wrapping setters into `Ember.run.later` or `Ember.run.scheduleOnce('afterRender',...)`. Btw you can also use `setProperties`.

```
didInsertElement() {
  this._super(...arguments);

  Ember.run.scheduleOnce('afterRender', () => {
    const self = this.$();

    this.setProperties({
      tracksWidth: self.width(),
      tracksOffset: self.offset(),
      tracksScrollWidth: self.get( 0 ).scrollWidth(),
      tracksScrollLeft: self.scrollLeft(),
      lastScrollPosition: self.scrollLeft(),
    });
  });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion, you shouldn't pass dimension of parent to the child component. There might be a way to do that with css. Even if it is not possible to do with pure css, there has to be a javascript way that every component should only know its own dimensions. At the end, you will not have to pass data that you get at `didRender` hook. That's my opinion.

Of course, sometimes you may need to use data you get at `didRender` hook. For those requirements, you can use [Ember Run Loop](https://guides.emberjs.com/v2.8.0/applications/run-loop/). (As mentioned by Keo at comments.)

Comment: `In my opinion, you shouldn't pass dimension of parent to the child component.` I agree, this looks more like deadline hack then proper solution.

Comment: It's not a deadline hack, it's recurring problem I had for the past year with the layout (roughly this one: https://jsfiddle.net/jcano/mjevq22a/1/). The wide divs are of different widths, but they should be aligned with each other and the categories on the left. Right side's horizontal scrollbar, should always be at the bottom of the window. The best solution would be to make the right-panel sticky, but they are not widely supported and even with sticky the implementation is tricky. Pure CSS is not possible otherwise. I could start a new question with this, if you are interested.

Comment: Yes, you are right. Sometimes pure css way could not be possible. For those cases, we try to find a way that every component only knows its own dimensions. Thus, our components can perfectly work within any component.